# Custom Symfony Action with API Platform bundle

Tags: php, symfony, api-platform.com

I try to build an API with the Symfony bundle [API-Platform](https://api-platform.com/).

Api resource offer automatic CRUD action with the HTTP verbs POST, GET, PUT, DELETE.

What I want is adding an endpoint to handle a custom POST action, with a custom payload/body, not depending on any resource.

Where I block it is to add this endpoint to the automatic API-Platform documentation.

When looking for this kind of issue on GitHub, I found that the API-Platform v2 should be able to do it.

See [**Issue #385 :** Custom action + ApiDoc](https://github.com/api-platform/core/issues/385)

It looks like some people find the way to use NelmioApiDoc @ApiDoc annotation.

See [**Issue #17 :** Documentation for custom operation](https://github.com/api-platform/api-platform/issues/17)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using the `@ApiDoc` annotation is a no go, support for NelmioApiDoc will be removed in API Platform 3 in favor of the builtin Swagger/Hydra support.

If you use a [custom API Platform action](https://api-platform.com/docs/core/operations), the action should automatically be documented in Swagger and Hydra docs.

Anyway, you can always customize the Swagger (and Hydra) docs to add custom endpoints or anything else: https://github.com/api-platform/docs/blob/master/core/swagger.md#override-swagger-documentation (this documentation will be available on the website soon).

Comment: Custom Action as describe in https://api-platform.com/docs/core/operations does not allow custom body/payload. The action still get a `$data` parameter which is an entity/resource created or update for POST or PUT methods.

Thanks for the Swagger link, I'll go see this as soon as possible.

Comment: Overriding Swagger only allows to manually add each custom parameter for each custom action. It does not provide automatic documentation for parameters or return type, like Nelmio did. I don't know if it is a goal for API-Platform. But as the API-Platform progresses and is put forward as the best api solution by Symfony Flex with `composer req api, I find it difficult to manage simple custom actions.

Comment: Using the v3 (currently in beta) of NelmioApiDoc looks like a good solution for now: https://github.com/nelmio/NelmioApiDocBundle/tree/v3.0.0-BETA4

It's clean and allows to keep the API Platform docs for builtin UI and use all NelmioApiDoc features for custom actions.

Comment: @KévinDunglas Do you have any update or new recommendation for this problem? Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can document your own route with the `@ApiResource()` annotation:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ApiResource(
 *     itemOperations={
 *         "get"={"method"="GET"},
 *         "put"={"method"="PUT"},
 *         "delete"={"method"="DELETE"},
 *         "send_reset_password_token"={
 *             "route_name"="user_send_reset_password_token",
 *              "swagger_context" = {
 *                 "parameters" = {
 *                     {
 *                         "name" = "email",
 *                         "in" = "path",
 *                         "required" = "true",
 *                         "type" = "string"
 *                     }
 *                 },
 *                 "responses" = {
 *                     "201" = {
 *                         "description" = "email with reset token has been sent",
 *                         "schema" =  {
 *                             "type" = "object",
 *                             "required" = {
 *                                 "email"
 *                             },
 *                             "properties" = {
 *                                  "email" = {
 *                                     "type" = "string"
 *                                  },
 *                                  "fullname" = {
 *                                     "type" = "string"
 *                                  }
 *                             }
 *                         }
 *                     },
 *                     "400" = {
 *                         "description" = "Invalid input"
 *                     },
 *                     "404" = {
 *                         "description" = "resource not found"
 *                     }
 *                 },
 *                 "summary" = "Send email with token to reset password",
 *                 "consumes" = {
 *                     "application/json",
 *                     "text/html",
 *                  },
 *                 "produces" = {
 *                     "application/json"
 *                  }
 *             }
 *         }
 *     },
 *     attributes={
 *         "normalization_context"={"groups"={"user", "user-read"}},
 *         "denormalization_context"={"groups"={"user", "user-write"}}
 *     }
 * )
 */
```

Source: https://github.com/api-platform/docs/issues/143#issuecomment-260221717

Answer (score 1):

You can create custom post action like this.
Map resources configuration to yaml.

```
# config/packages/api_platform.yaml
api_platform:
enable_swagger_ui: false
mapping:
    paths: ['%kernel.project_dir%/config/api_platform']
```

Create resources.yaml

```
# config/api_platform/resources.yaml
resources:
App\Entity\User:
  itemOperations: []
  collectionOperations:
    post:
        method: 'POST'
        path: '/auth'
        controller: App\Controller\AuthController
        swagger_context:
            summary: your desc
            description: your desc
```

Then in App\Entity\User add public properties

```
class User {
   public $login
   public $password
}
```

It is all, now in swagger ui u will see method POST /api/auth with login and pass parameters.

In u controller override _invoke for execute your logic.

```
class AuthController {
   public function __invoke()
   {
      return ['your custom answer'];
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same situation because I tried to put the POST method into `itemOperations`, although it can only reside in `collectionOperations`. In the latter in can successfully define my custom path.

```
/**
 * @ApiResource(
 *     collectionOperations={
 *       "get"={
 *           "path"="/name_your_route",
 *       },
 *       "post"={
 *           "path"="/name_your_route",
 *       },
 *     },
 *     itemOperations={
 *       "get"={
 *           "path"="/name_your_route/group/{groupId}/user/{userId}",
 *           "requirements"={"groupId"="\d+", "userId"="\d+"},
 *       },
 *       "delete"={
 *           "path"="/name_your_route/group/{groupId}/user/{userId}",
 *       },
 *       "put"={
 *           "path"="/name_your_route/group/{groupId}/user/{userId}",
 *       }
 * })
```

Hopefully helpful for others that stumble upon this question.

And here is the paragraph from [the great documentation about it](https://api-platform.com/docs/core/operations):

> Collection operations act on a collection of resources. By default two
>   routes are implemented: POST and GET. Item operations act on an
>   individual resource. 3 default routes are defined GET, PUT and DELETE