# renaming custom operation in api-platform

Tags: api-platform.com

I'm modeling one entity that has a prepare-release workflow. So in addition to the ordinary POST action to create the entity, I also have a second POST custom operation to set it active. This triggers considerable backend activity which is why I implement it as a custom operation and not as a simple update on a property (PUT).

So far so good, however in the API interface documentation, it still describes the operation as "create a xxx resource", which is false. I found no way to change this description. How can I put a different text there?

Answer (score 1):

actually figured out from a totally unrelated post (https://stackoverflow.com/a/49534635/982364) that this works:

```
 *     collectionOperations={"post", "special"={
 *         "method"="PUT",
 *         "path"="/myentity/{id}/commit",
 *         "controller"=EntitySpecial::class,
 *         "denormalization_context"={"groups"={"myentity_commit"}},
 *         "swagger_context" = {
 *              "summary" = "commit to this action"
 *         },
 *         "defaults"={"_api_receive"=false}
 *     }},
```