# API Platform - Custom controller / action description annotations not working

Tags: api-platform.com

Really sorry if I've missed something here, but I have searched the issues and docs high and low, and I cannot find why this is not working. Perhaps I need another tutorial on using the internet ;)

Consider the following entity annotation, in the `openapi_context` section the `body.description` and `responses.200.description` have no effect at all, and its driving me slightly mad... You should know that I am using de/normalization contexts but that doesn't seem related so I have left it out.

```
/**
 * User entity
 *
 * @API\ApiResource(
 *  collectionOperations={
 *      "authenticate"={
 *          "method"="POST",
 *          "status"=200,
 *          "path"="/authenticate",
 *          "controller"=UserLoginController::class,
 *          "openapi_context"={
 *              "responses"={"200"={"description"="API token and secret"}},
 *              "body"={"description"="Login details"},
 *              "summary"="User authentication",
 *              "description"="Provides auth tokens on success",
 *          },
 *      },
 *  }
 * )
 *
 */
class User implements UserInterface
{
    ...
}
```

The result (blue blocks as expected, red blocks not working):
[image]

I have spent way too much time on this issue as it is, I would really appreciate it if someone could help me put this to bed. I have checked/tried the following to no avail;

- [Creating Custom Operations and Controllers](https://api-platform.com/docs/core/controllers/)
- [Custom Symfony Action with API Platform bundle](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49534635/629157)
- [[Question] Documentation API with Swagger #143](https://github.com/api-platform/docs/issues/143)
- [Changing Operations in the OpenAPI Documentation](https://api-platform.com/docs/core/openapi/#changing-operations-in-the-openapi-documentation)

Composer versions (relevant parts):

```
{
    "require": {
        "php": ">=7.2.5",
        "api-platform/core": "^2.6",
        "symfony/framework-bundle": "5.2.*"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some experimenting, I found that the `openapi_context` annotation attribute does indeed seems to ignore the response documentation. It does however allow you to provide the request body description that you are missing:

```php
#[ApiResource(
    collectionOperations: [
        'test' => [
            'method' => 'POST',
            'path' => '/test',
            'openapi_context' => [
                'summary' => 'The endpoint summary',
                'description' => 'The endpoint description',
                'requestBody' => [
                    'description' => 'The endpoint request body description', // This one
                    'content' => [
                        'application/json' => [
                            'schema' => [
                                '$ref' => '#/components/schemas/MyResource-some.group'
                            ],
                        ],
                    ],
                ],
            ],
        ]
    ],
)]
```

*I'm using PHP `8.0.3` and API Platform `2.6.3` while writing this, changing the annotations to docblocks should result in the same outcome for you though.*

In order to document the endpoint response specification however, I had to implement a custom [OpenApiFactoryInterface](https://api-platform.com/docs/core/openapi/#overriding-the-openapi-specification):

```php
<?php declare(strict_types = 1);

namespace App;

use ApiPlatform\Core\OpenApi\Factory\OpenApiFactoryInterface;
use ApiPlatform\Core\OpenApi\Model\Operation;
use ApiPlatform\Core\OpenApi\Model\PathItem;
use ApiPlatform\Core\OpenApi\Model\RequestBody;
use ApiPlatform\Core\OpenApi\OpenApi;
use ArrayObject;
use UnexpectedValueException;

class MyResourceOpenApiFactory implements OpenApiFactoryInterface
{
    private OpenApiFactoryInterface $openApiFactory;

    public function __construct(OpenApiFactoryInterface $openApiFactory)
    {
        $this->openApiFactory = $openApiFactory;
    }

    public function __invoke(array $context = []): OpenApi
    {
        $openApi = ($this->openApiFactory)($context);
        $components = $openApi->getComponents();
        $schemas = $components->getSchemas();
        if (null === $schemas) {
            throw new UnexpectedValueException('Failed to obtain OpenApi schemas');
        }

        $pathItem = new PathItem(
            'MyResource test endpoint',
            'A test summary',
            'A test description',
            null,
            null,
            // Your custom post operation
            new Operation(
                'testMyResourceCollection', // the operation route name
                [
                    'MyResource' // your resource name
                ],
                [
                    // response specifications
                    '201' => [
                        'description' => 'test endpoint 201 response description',
                        'content' => [
                            'application/json' => [
                                'schema' => [
                                    '$ref' => '#/components/schemas/MyResource-read', // your resource (read) schema
                                ],
                            ],
                        ],
                    ],
                ],
                'A test endpoint summary',
                'A test endpoint description',
                null,
                [],
                new RequestBody(
                    'A test request body description',
                    new ArrayObject([
                        'application/json' => [
                            'schema' => [
                                '$ref' => '#/components/schemas/MyResource-write', // your resource (write) schema
                            ],
                        ],
                    ]),
                ),
            ),
        );

        $paths = $openApi->getPaths();
        $paths->addPath('/my_resources/test', $pathItem);
        return $openApi;
    }
}
```

Have this `OpenApiFactoryInterface` implementation wired by the service container as a decorator to `api_platform.openapi.factory`:

```yaml
App\MyResourceOpenApiFactory:
    decorates: 'api_platform.openapi.factory'
    autoconfigure: false
```

Change the references to the example `MyResource` name to a resource name of your choice (like `User`).

**Sidenote:**
This whole process of customizing OpenApi endpoint documentation in API Platform is currently quite convoluted in my opinion. Use the implementation I provided as a reference to your own implementation, as you most likely need to make a few adjustments to it in order to make it satisfy your specific use case.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I have prematurely marked it as correct as I was about to look into Open API factory (as per advice on one of their reported issues) and based on what you've explained it seems the best approach. I am assuming the interface will replace the annotation for `openapi_context`, thanks for this. A big +1 from me